# What is wrong with this forall -statement in CPLEX?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I am trying to answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231528/how-can-i-do-functions-in-cplex) but err:

```
   forall(t in 0..4){
    a[t]<=z[t];
    -a[t]<=z[t];
    x[t+1]==x[t]+v[t];
    v[t+1]==v[t]+a[t];
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive equation enters into un-initialized interval hence index out of exeption. You can avoid this bug by tweaking: initialize not-needed valuations and assign them to zero.

This creates some overhead but simplifies the logic, cannot think about any simpler way to do this.