# CPLEX -linear-optimization-program for Unix?

Tags: unix, optimization, linear-programming, cplex

The linear-optimization course 2.3140 requires CPLEX but it is pain to use because poorly-documented and hard-to-get any information when a brick wall like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231528/how-can-i-do-functions-in-cplex) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291906/what-is-wrong-with-this-forall-statement-in-cplex), let alone not having the software locally.

Does there exist some linear-optimization -tool by which I could program like with CPLEX? Since I haven't used this tool for a year, I have forgotten a lot of trivial things. Now trying to find some tool that I could run even in my Debian comp or Apple -comp, any tool or lib existing?

**Trial 1: Trying to find GUI -tool to execute code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13285562/164148)**

> Trying to understand how the CPLEX works from IBM Academic Initiative. In uni, I have some sort of Eclipse CPLEX -thing but I found only this -- where can I get the GUI thing for some Unix? Image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4d9b.png).

Answer (score 1):

There is a ton of documentation available from [ibm](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/websphere/ilog/docs/optimization/cplex/).  If you want the software on your local machine and are a student, you can get it through the [academic initiative](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21419058).  If you want to try something different and are a student, you can get [gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/?utm_expid=11945996-12), which has a python interface you might like.

Comment: ...trying to get the CPLEX working in Ubuntu but some bugs [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/218224/how-to-get-this-java-program-cplex-working-in-ubuntu-11).

Comment: I got some CPLEX studio -thing from Academic Initiative, +1 for it, but cannot find any GUI -- I got CLI like this [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r4d9b.png) -- how can I execute code?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to look at the COIN-OR website here:

http://www.coin-or.org/

They provide well-documented libraries and solvers (I use CPLEX mostly, so I don't use those much, but it is well documented and looks really good).

CPLEX alone does a lot of things, but for a linear programming course you will probably only need a tool to solve linear programs, and maybe mixed-integer problems (MIP).

Have a look at CMPL from coin, this may be enough for you; if you need to write "real" programs, you will have to use a (C or C++) library. They provide CoinMP for MIPs, and Clp for linear programs (simplex, barrier algorithms).

I have also used GLPK (from the GNU project) for linear programs, but it performs poorly for MIP (the default branch-and-bound procedure is very simple), although it may be enough for your course:

http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/

However, I don't really agree with you about the fact that CPLEX documentation is poor..

Answer (score 0):

**Python**

> I haven't tested CVXOPT but my teacher mocked it, apparently a bit buggy, more [here](http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/).